# Line break after printing array's element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, newline, line-breaks

So I have this code which checks if an element of array starts with letter Ա/ա, and prints it by adding into a paragraph. But I can not make every word start from a new line.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < aremove.length; i++) {
  aremove = [...new Set(aremove)].sort()
  if (/^[Աա]/.test(aremove[i])) {
    var word = document.createTextNode(aremove[i])
    document.getElementById("p").appendChild(word)
  }
}
```

If I add `+"<br>"`, it's not breaking the line but simply adds `<br>` to words. If I add `.join("<br>")` it returns "TypeError: aremove[i].join is not a function" or "word.join is not a function" and so on...

Comment: Create and append `<br>` element.

Comment: Its a bad practice to mutate DOM in a loop. So is using `<br/>`. Instead create a `<p>` tag and add it to a fragment. Then at the end of loop, replace element

Comment: @Rajesh Only if you're thrashing the DOM, i.e. read a property which forces layout recalculation in a loop, that doesn't happen in OP's code.

Comment: @Teemu OP is adding child. That will trigger a repaint and reflow as well. Fragment is always better in my opinion in such cases

Comment: @Rajesh Not in the loop, the recalculation takes place after the script has been executed. But I can agree with the use of a fragment even in this case (there might be something read triggering the reflow later in the script).

Comment: @Teemu That I doubt. For example, if I have a mutation listener, it will fire for all elements and not at the end. I'm also not sure how to verify, but based on my experience, both `<br/>` and adding/ removing elements in loop used to be bad. One of the primary reason for using virtual/ shadow dom. But I have been wrong before. Would not mind to learn something new

Comment: @Rajesh You can use the DevTools to check when the reflow takes place. JS and events are run in the same thread, events won't fire before the current script has been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By help of Teemu's comment

```js
for (i = 0; i < aremove.length; i++) {
  aremove = [...new Set(aremove)].sort()
  if (/^[Աա]/.test(aremove[i])) {
    word = document.createTextNode(aremove[i])
    linebreak = document.createElement("br")
    document.getElementById("girq").appendChild(word)
    document.getElementById("girq").appendChild(linebreak)
  }
}
```

I have created a `"br"` element, and as I can't append an element and text node at once, I appended it separately.